# my domain name is not working properly?

Tags: web, dns

basically i have a website i.e www.example.com

when i enter www.example.com it deosnt work
but when i enter http://example.com it works why is this happening!!

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you ping your website just pinging example.com ?

Comment: Going to http://kornar.com takes me to a different site than www.kornar.com this is very strange!

Comment: put more info language,CMS,framework etc

Comment: It's definitely a server thing. I don't know much about what exactly is going on, but it's somewhere in the ball park of how different websites will use www2, www, or route traffic through both. I have no clue, though. This was just an interesting question. Good luck!

Comment: Have you newly registered this domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify an a address for both www. and no-www

@   - A address OR CNAME 255.255.255.255 180

www - A address OR CNAME 255.255.255.255 180

They are called host records .

Comment: how do i chnage the cname from plesk

Comment: Visit Desktop > youdomain.com > services >
add record > select CNAME.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that both www.kornar.com and kornar.com are correctly set to resolve to the same IP address.  However, it seems like your Apache install isn't set to handle www.kornar.com correctly.  If you're using some sort of virtual hosting, you need to ensure that the server recognizes and host names that you want it to respond to.

It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong without more information on what webserver you're running and what it's configuration is.